# MySQL: Using NULL as wildcard in JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, null, inner-join

I have a table containing perfectly defined items and a second table with potentially vague/greedy orders as NULL would require all available values for this parameter.

```
items
+-----------------------+
| item_id | color | size |
|---------+-------+------|
|    1    |  blue |    8 |
|    2    |   red |    6 |
|    3    | green |    7 |
|    4    | black |    6 |
+------------------------+

orders
+-------------------------+
| order_id | color | size |
|----------+-------+------|
|     1    |   red |    6 |
|     2    | green |    8 |
|     3    |  NULL |    6 |
|     4    |  blue | NULL |
|     5    |  NULL | NULL |
+-------------------------+
```

Is there an efficient way to generate a complete list of items needed to fill all orders?

```
+--------------------+
| order_id | item_id |
|----------+---------|
|     1    |    2    |
|     3    |    2    |
|     3    |    4    |
|     4    |    1    |
|     5    |    1    |
|     5    |    2    |
|     5    |    3    |
|     5    |    4    |
+--------------------+
```

It seems to me like an INNER JOIN should be able to do this, but something like this obviously doesn't consider the possibility of NULL values as greedy wildcards in the *orders* table:

```sql
SELECT order_id, item_id
FROM orders
INNER JOIN items ON orders.color = items.color AND orders.size = items.size
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT order_id, item_id
FROM orders
INNER JOIN items ON (orders.color IS NULL OR orders.color = items.color)
    AND (orders.size IS NULL OR orders.size = items.size)
```

Let me know if that helps, or if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite the conditions for the `JOIN` you can get the desired result:

```
SELECT order_id, item_id
FROM orders
JOIN items
    ON ((orders.color = items.color OR orders.color IS NULL)
        AND (orders.size = items.size OR orders.size IS NULL))
```

However, the orders table should probably look more like the result of this query than the current orders table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `IFNULL` function for this:

```
SELECT order_id, item_id
  FROM orders
  JOIN items ON IFNULL(orders.color, items.color) = items.color
            AND IFNULL(orders.size, items.size) = items.size
```

If the value in orders is null, then it'll use the value from items (and thus match).