# How can i use null value as a wildcard to join in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have the same problem as this topic
[MySQL: Using NULL as wildcard in JOIN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829110/mysql-using-null-as-wildcard-in-join-statement)

Would like to find a solution by using Power Query

```
items
+-----------------------+
| item_id | color | size |
|---------+-------+------|
|    1    |  blue |    8 |
|    2    |   red |    6 |
|    3    | green |    7 |
|    4    | black |    6 |
+------------------------+

orders
+-------------------------+
| order_id | color | size |
|----------+-------+------|
|     1    |   red |    6 |
|     2    | green |    8 |
|     3    |  NULL |    6 |
|     4    |  blue | NULL |
|     5    |  NULL | NULL |
+-------------------------+
```

Expected out

```
items
+--------------------+
| order_id | item_id |
|----------+---------|
|     1    |    2    |
|     3    |    2    |
|     3    |    4    |
|     4    |    1    |
|     5    |    1    |
|     5    |    2    |
|     5    |    3    |
|     5    |    4    |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in one shot

```
//order table
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"order_id", Int64.Type}, {"color", type text}, {"size", Int64.Type}}),
Buffer=Table.Buffer(items),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","data",(i)=>Table.SelectRows(Buffer, each 
    i[color]=null and i[size]=null or
    i[color]=null and i[size]=[size] or 
    i[color]=[color] and i[size]=null or
    i[color]=[color] and i[size]=[size]
) [item_id]),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "data"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded data", each ([data] <> null)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"color", "size"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Or do it in pieces with merges, then combine, which would likely be faster for huge data sets

```
//order table
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"order_id", Int64.Type}, {"color", type text}, {"size", Int64.Type}}),

#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([color] <> null) and ([size] <> null)),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows", {"color", "size"}, items, {"color", "size"}, "items", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded items" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "items", {"item_id"}, {"item_id"}),

 #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([color] = null) and ([size] <> null)),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows2", {"size"}, items, {"size"}, "items", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded items1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "items", {"item_id"}, {"item_id"}),

#"Filtered Rows3" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([color] <> null) and ([size] = null)),
#"Merged Queries2" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows3", {"color"}, items, {"color"}, "items", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded items2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries2", "items", {"item_id"}, {"item_id"}),

#"Filtered Rows4" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([color] = null) and ([size] = null)),
BlankFill=Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows4","item_id", each  items[item_id]),
#"Expanded item_id" = Table.ExpandListColumn(BlankFill, "item_id"),

combined = #"Expanded items" & #"Expanded items1" & #"Expanded items2" & #"Expanded item_id",
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(combined,{"color", "size"}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([item_id] <> null))

in #"Filtered Rows1"
```

[image]